Magento upgrade: Failed to download elasticsearch/elasticsearch from dist
I am doing some upgrade testing for Magento - trying to upgrade from 2.4.4 to 2.4.6. When I run the 'composer update' command it is erroring with the following:
 384/511 [=====================>------]  75%    Failed to download elasticsearch/elasticsearch from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/elastic/elasticsearch-php/zipball/2d302233f2bb0926812d82823bb820d405e130fc" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
    Now trying to download from source

It then tries to download Elasticsearch from source and this returns the following errors:
  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'https://<removed_for_security>:***@github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php.git' '/home/www/.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-elastic-elasticsearch-php.git/'

  Cloning into bare repository '/home/www/.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-elastic-elasticsearch-php.git'...
  remote: Repository not found.
  fatal: repository 'https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php.git/' not found

Commands that I ran to get this error:
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6 --no-update
composer update

How can I work around this so that the upgrade process does not abort?

We are aware that some of our public repositories are temporarily unavailable and are working towards resolving this. See https://status.elastic.co/incidents/9mmlp98klxm1
